# Custom post type archive with rand and meta_value

Tags: meta-query, order

I have a custom post type that have a meta_key `custom_meta_sponsored` that owns alphabetical values. "X" means post doesn't sponsored. I want to show the archive page in custom order, sponsored first in random order.

I use `pre_get_posts` hook, but it doesn't work as I expected:

```
function custom_loops($query) {
    if ( is_post_type_archive('my_post_type') ){
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 40);
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'custom_meta_sponsored');
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value rand');
        //$query->set( 'order', 'DESC');
    }
    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_loops' );
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_loops');
```

In the result sponsored posts display first and nearly random. I mean sponsored posts in randon by a kind of date order. Newly created posts are always display first. I would like to display sponsored post fully random regardless of creation date. Any idea?

Comment: You'll need two loops

Comment: Dear kraftner, could you please give me some instructions how to solve two loops. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `'posts_orderby'` filter:

```
function custom_loops($query) {
    if ( is_post_type_archive('my_post_type') ){
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 40);
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'custom_meta_sponsored');
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'custom_meta_sponsored');
        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC');
        add_filter( 'posts_orderby', function ( $orderby, $query ) {
            if ( $query->get( 'orderby' ) != 'custom_meta_sponsored' ) return $orderby;
            global $wpdb;
            $orderby = $wpdb->prepare(
                'CASE WHEN ' . $wpdb->postmeta . '.meta_value != %s THEN CONCAT(%s, RAND()) ELSE '
                . $wpdb->posts . '.post_date END ' . $query->get( 'order' )
                , 'X', 'z'
            );
            return $orderby;
        }, 10, 2 );
    }
    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_loops' );
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_loops');
```

Comment: It almost works posts display in fully random order, but some posts appear on first and second pages as well. :/ Probably I should use two loops in the template file. Could you please give me some instructions how to do this?

Comment: Oh I just noticed non-sponsored are "X", not 0 - need to change CASE WHEN to check for this - will update answer...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I created two loops. With a `foreach` I go through the main query results `$wp_query->posts` and reordering posts.

Thank you.